# Exim conditional logic

Tags: email-server, exim

I am trying to have exim check the domain of outgoing and incoming mails against a domainlist. If the FROM address of the outgoing mail and the TO/CC/BCC address of the incoming mail are not in the list of local domains, I want to reject/discard the message. Below is what I have come up with, placed in the "acl_not_smpt" section:

```
discard
condition = ${if and {{! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_from:}}}{+local_domains}}\
{if or {\
{! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_to:}}}{+local_domains}}}\
{! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_cc:}}}{+local_domains}}}\
{! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_bcc:}}}{+local_domains}}}\
}\
}\
}\
message = Mail discarded for spoofing
```

But I am getting the below error in my exim log:

> unknown condition "if" inside "and{...}" condition

Very new to exim syntax, some help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The second `if` is incorrect and in fact you don't need it: the `and` conditions can use any boolean function (cf. [expansion conditions](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html#SECTexpcond)), while `$if` returns a string (cf. [expansion items](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html#SECTexpansionitems) and [expansion operators](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html#SECTexpop)). There are also some additional `}`. A working condition becomes:

```
condition = ${if and {\
              {!match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_from:}}}{+local_domains}}\
              { or {\
                {! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_to:}}}{+local_domains}}\
                {! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_cc:}}}{+local_domains}}\
                {! match_domain{${domain:${address:$h_bcc:}}}{+local_domains}}\
              }}\
            }}
```

This condition has some bugs: it does check not for multiple recipients and `From:` addresses.

Remark also that the **acl_not_smtp** ACL is run only when a (local) user invokes exim4 with the [-bm or -bS option](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-how_exim_receives_and_delivers_mail.html#SECID13). That means your ACL will block local users from sending outgoing mail.

If that's what you want to do, then your expression can be simplified:

- The check on `From:` header can be done more effectively configuring Exim's [trusted users](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html#SECTtrustedadmin).
- Instead of checking separately for the `To:`, `Cc:` and `Bcc:`, you can use the `$recipients` variable, that contains all of them in a `,` separated string.

All of this amounts to two ACL stanzas:

```
  accept
    condition = ${if forall {<,${recipients}}\
                  {match_domain{${domain:${item}}}{+local_domains}}\
                }
  deny
```

In general you can debug your string expansions and non-`SMTP` ACLs by creating (or saving) and e-mail (lets say to `email.eml`) and running:

```
exim4 -d-all+acl+expand -bm -t < email.eml
```

as root (**warning**: this will attempt a real e-mail delivery), while to check just the expansions run:

```
exim4 -bem email.eml
```