# Exim - restrict which addresses a user can send from

Tags: exim

By default, exim allows any user to send out an email with any "From:" address they wish, which can lead to users spoofing each other. How do I restrict which addresses each system user can send from? For example the user `james` should be able to send from james@localhost, but also me@my-domain.com and james@other-domain.com.

I want all system users to be able to send email from their SYSTEM_USER@HOSTNAME, but if they attempt to send from another address I want to look up that address in a text file to see if it is allowed.

I currently have a list, but it is for what addresses a system user will receive from. But it could still work. Given the example `me@my-domain.com` the data is stored in the file `/etc/exim4/virtual/my-domain.com` where the content looks like:

```
me : james@localhost
```

If we could reuse the existing files that would be great. But any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how are they siending  (SMTP or /usr/bin/sendmail)?,  which from address (envelope sdender or from heeader)?

Comment: Both, and both :-) I'd like to write a rule which covers all cases.

Comment: Basically you need a couple of ACL rules (cf. a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/999324/530633), but for recipients) to check the envelope sender and the `From` and `Sender` headers.

Comment: Yes thanks, sounds like it. Even though I have years of experience writing code in various languages, I just can't wrap my head around exim configurations. Any chance you could get me started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exim4** already does some standard checks on the envelope sender, `From:` and `Sender:` of the locally submitted messages (cf. [trusted users](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html#SECTtrustedadmin)). Since you want to extend this validation you should:

- For messages submitted through `sendmail` (i.e. `exim4 -bm`), add to the main configuration section:

  ```
  # allow untrusted users to set an envelope sender
  untrusted_set_sender = *
  # don't delete the Sender: header
  local_sender_retain = true
  # don't add Sender: header
  local_from_check = false
  ```
- For messages submitted through `SMTP` you need to add the `control = submission/sender_retain` modifier. E.g. Debian has in the `MAIL` acl a rule:

  ```
  accept
    authenticated = *
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify
  ```

To configure your check you need to add a couple of `ACL` rules at different stages of mail processing. Since these rules need to be applied to different ways of message submission you can create a new named `ACL` (I assume that all your `/etc/exim4/virtual/<domain>` files return `username@localhost` as value):

```
# Requires system user id in $acl_arg1
acl_check_sender:

  # Users with default domain
  accept
    condition = ${if eq{$sender_address}{$acl_arg1@$qualify_domain}}
    condition = ${if eq{${address:$h_from:}}{$acl_arg1@$qualify_domain}}
    condition = ${if match_address{${address:$h_sender:}}{:$acl_arg1@$qualify_domain}}

  deny
    ! condition = ${if and{\
        {exists{/etc/exim4/virtual/${domain:${address:$h_from:}}}}\
        {eq {${acl_arg1}@localhost}\
          {${lookup {${local_part:${address:$h_from:}}}\
            lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/${domain:${address:$h_from:}}}\
          }}\
        }\
      }}
    message = Spoofed From: header.

  # Most messages don't have a Sender: header, but if it is not empty, check it.
  deny
    ! condition = ${if or{\
        {eq {$h_sender:}{}}\
        {and{\
          {exists{/etc/exim4/virtual/${domain:${address:$h_sender:}}}}\
          {eq {${acl_arg1}@localhost}\
              {${lookup {${local_part:${address:$h_sender:}}}\
                lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/${domain:${address:$h_sender:}}}\
              }}\ 
          }\
        }}\
      }}
    message = Spoofed Sender: header.

  deny
    ! condition = ${if and{\
        {exists{/etc/exim4/virtual/$sender_address_domain}}\
        {eq {${acl_arg1}@localhost}\
          {${lookup {$sender_address_local_part}\
            lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/$sender_address_domain}\
          }}\
        }\
      }}
    message = Spoofed envelope sender.

  accept
```

For the syntax of string expansion (quite full of braces), check [chapter 11](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html) of Exim's documentation. You can use `exim4 -bem <message> <expansion_string>` to test them (the envelope sender is passed in the message like the **mbox** format).

You can apply it to different situations:

- For messages submitted through `exim4 -bm`, add to the `acl_not_smtp` ACL the following rule:

  ```
  deny
    ! acl = acl_check_sender ${sender_ident}
  ```
- For messages submitted by authenticated users through `SMTP` add to the `acl_smtp_data` ACL something like:

  ```
  deny
    authenticated = *
    ! acl = acl_check_sender ${authenticated_id}
  ```
- Some programs submit messages using a **non**-authenticated `SMTP` connection to `localhost` (or `exim -bs`). For them you can add to the `acl_smtp_data` ACL:

  ```
  deny
    hosts = : localhost
    ! acl = acl_check_sender ${sender_ident}
  ```

  and install some **identd** on the server.

Comment: Thanks so much! That got me on the right track. You switched your arguments round though in the statements, but I was able to sort that. Also, if no file existed for a domain it would temporarily fail rather than reject, but I fixed that too. I'll post my solution separately soon.

Comment: Things I can't fix: If you set `untrusted_set_sender = *`, then for some obscure reason exim no longer populates $authenticated_id, it's just bank. So unless you can tell me another way to find the local username for a non-smtp email then it is impossible to filter locally sent mail. For the moment I don't use `acl_check_sender` for non-smtp mail and have just disabled being able to set custom From: addresses for local mail (if you want to do that, use smtp).

Comment: And last, but not least. The setup works fine, except if blocks all mail **unless** they have a file in the the `/virtual/` folder. My intention was to use the `virtual` folder only for aliases in addition to a user's @localhost account. I've been trying to think how to write a condition to not match if the mail is from localhost, but I don't know the variable to use to get the local system name. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the messed up rules and added a rule for the default domain (which is in the variable `$qualify_domain`).

Comment: You should probably post your answer as an **answer** instead of modifying the question.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping you would so I could mark your answer correct. I see you've added the file exists check as a separate condition. That was my first attempt, but Exim ANDs conditions, don't we need this lack of file existance to be ORed with the other rule? I haven't actually tried your code yet. Can you confirm for me if you want the conditions in your new deny case to be ORed or ANDed? Thank you

Comment: I just tried out your new rule, it works perfectly! Thank you! So there's just the question of how to find $authorized_id for trusted local users (currently it is blank).

Comment: Apparently for **trusted users**  the `$authenticated_id` variable is unset, but `$sender_ident` isn't. I corrected the example in the answer.

Comment: When I enable the not_smtp rule, I suddenly become unable to send any mail from the mail command (whether changing the from or not). Looking in the log, for each attempt there is an entry which lists the from F=example@example.com, but then the next line has F=<> with the message `Error while reading message with no usable sender address`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `log_message` to the `deny` rules to debug it.